# MS Access select query using parameters fails

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I'm using an Access DB as a backend for a classic asp web page. I'm creating a saved query that uses parameters. I'm testing in the query builder in Access 2000. The fields are all text, default value is NULL, zero length allowed for the [in_b]s, of which there are 9, named B160, B80, B40, B30 etc.

My query is:

```
 SELECT COUNT([in_b]) AS BCnt FROM tblScore 
 WHERE UCALL=[in_call] and NOT ISNULL([in_b]);
```

This returns a count of all rows for a given UCALL. If I change either of the 2[in_b] to the actual column name, the query gives me what I want (0 in this case), but then I'd have to run 9 querys.

Example of table

```
Call  Zone B160   B80  B40
NF4L   1    NULL   X    NULL
NF4L   6    Null  Null  NULL
NF4L   20     X     X   Null
WA4B   2    NULL  NULL   X

If in_call is NF4L and in_b is B160, I expect 1
If in_call is NF4L and in_b is B80,  I expect 2
If in_call is NF4L and in_b is B40,  I expect 0
```

The goal is to get a count of all "B" columns that are not empty for a given call.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are using your parameter ([in_b]) as a reference to a column, not an actual data value. I don't think you'll get very far with this design.

In addition to constructing 9 different queries (Don't do it!) there are two other options you might try to pursue:

1. Change your table design to be more of a key-value pair
2. Construct your query dynamically based on the conditions you are provided

For option 1, you could alter your table to look like this:

```
Call | Zone | BField | BFieldValue
NF4L | 1    | B80    | X
NF4L | 1    | B160   | NULL
NF4L | 1    | B40    | NULL
NF4L | 6    | B160   | NULL
NF4L | 6    | B80    | NULL
NF4L | 6    | B40    | NULL
NF4L | 20   | B160   | X
NF4L | 20   | B80    | X
NF4L | 20   | B40    | NULL
...
```

Your query could then look something like this:

```
SELECT BField, COUNT([BFieldValue]) AS BCnt 
FROM tblScore 
WHERE UCALL=[in_call] and [BFieldValue] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY BField;
```

This option is the more extensible of the two. If you need to add additional "BFields" at some point it is trivial to do so, but comes at a cost of having to redesign the table how you add data to the table.

Option 2 would be to construct your query dynamically at runtime so you can substitute in the actual column name based upon the conditions you've outlined. For example:

```
Dim SQL as String
Dim BField as String
Dim InCall as String

'These would typically be passed in, not hardcoded as they are here
Set InCall = "NF4L"
Set BField = "B160"

SET SQL = "SELECT Count([" & BField & "] FROM tblScore WHERE [Call] ='" & InCall & "' AND NOT ISNULL([" & BField & "]);"

'From here, either open up a recordset based on this SQL or create a new QueryDef object and execute it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know using SQL Server, you can pass a parameter and use a `CASE` statement, something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Test
WHERE CASE 
   WHEN @col = 'col1'
   THEN col1 
   WHEN @col = 'col2' 
   THEN col2 END IS NOT NULL
```

Where @col is the passed in parameter.  I think you can do this in MS Access using `IIF` -- give this a try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Test
WHERE NOT ISNULL(IIF(@col = 'col1', col1, IIF(@col = 'col2', col2, ...))
```

Alternatively, you could do this server side using dynamic SQL, but make sure you use parameterized queries.  Here's a good example:

```
Const ad_nVarChar = 202
Const ad_ParamInput = 1

strSQL = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tblScore WHERE [Call] = ? AND NOT ISNULL(?); "

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")    
cmd.ActiveConnection = connStr
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.Parameters(0) = "NF4L"
cmd.Parameters(1) = "B160"

Set rst = cmd.Execute()
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for that, I appreciate your time and effort. Before I read your answer, I changed my table design to have only cols for Call, Zone, and Band, filling Band with values like B160, B80 etc.